# Problem Python 3.9: trying to install package 'PyPortfolioOpt'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried downloading the 'PyPortfolioOpt' package on my MacBook Pro (iOS 11.0.1) but it always shows an error.
I've downloaded the Xcode developer tools and already upgraded the latest pip3 setup-tools. I am using python 3.9.

The error:

### 1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1

ERROR: Failed building wheel for cvxopt
Running setup.py clean for cvxopt
Failed to build cvxopt
Installing collected packages: cvxopt, PyPortfolioOpt
Running setup.py install for cvxopt ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, probably something to do with how new python 3.9 is and how little bug fixes have come out so far, python 3.9 didn't work for me at all. I have upgraded a few times before, but never did it result in as many bugs as when I tried installing python 3.9. I recommend firstly trying `$ python3 -m pip install PyPortfolioOpt`, and if that doesn't work go back to python 3.8 or 3.7, that's what I'm on now and everything works fine now for me.